# performance openvino demo error --- python:command not found

Tags: python, hyperlink, centos7, onnx, openvino

when I execute follow script in the vm,it take place this erro:
(yolox_torch) [root@localhost cenos]# cd /opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/install_prerequisites/
(yolox_torch) [root@localhost install_prerequisites]# ./install_prerequisites_onnx.sh
sudo: python3.6: command not found
Error on or near line 64; exiting with status 1

I try to modify the python link,but it failed.
help!!

Answer (score 1):

The error means that Python is not installed or your installation is damaged. Reinstalling Python will solve the error. Also, make sure to always run the *setupvars.sh* script before running any OpenVINO code. Refer to the instructions in the following guide:
https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_linux.html